# Salesforce Data Entry Journey is created duplicated subscriber keys - Is there a way to fix this?

Tags: marketing-cloud, duplicate-management

We have a journey that uses Salesforce Entry Data as the event to get into the journey. Our salesforce contacts are already synched in our system. The journey is working but it is creating new subscribers for the people entering the journey. How do we fix this?

Here is are some additional details:

- Journey is set for re-entry but only have completing
- We are using the email address from the entry source

Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So let me get this straight: Journey Builder> Entry Object is Contact > Contact: Email  is being used, but for some reason, it's not sending to the email associated to that contact. Is that correct?

Comment: what do the newly created subscriberKeys look like? - emails? 003xxxxx Ids? 001xxxxx Ids?

Comment: @chorlesbarkley7 That is correct, so I now have two duplication emails for that person. but the email from the journey is the only one being sent. The other is not used.

Comment: @JonasLamberty It is using the ID from the object in Salesforce. So we use a provider order object for the trigger for the journey. It is taking that id number and creating a new contact in MC with that as the contact key.

Comment: @chorlesbarkley7 Sorry I need to update my answer to your question. Journey Builder > Salesforce Data Entry > Email from entry source.

Comment: @AndrewC What object are you syncing as the entry event? It sounds like one of two things is happening: 1) You have an entry even that is not associated with the contact object e.g lead object, and previously you sync'd with the lead object. This would create 2 different subkeys. 2) You are syncing on the contact object, however, you previously imported these addresses using a different key e.g. email. This would also cause duplication. Can you verify what your entry source is in JB?

Answer (score 2):

Judging from your answer in the comments I understand you are using a custom object to provide your Ids.

That sounds good, until you observe what you are seeing now:

That approach is not compatible with how Journey Builder wants to work with MC Connect features like Salesforce Entry Event. in short: that's "expected behavior".

Journey Builder only injects "persons", and from SF, only the three (objects Lead, Contact or User can be "the person in the journey".

Sidenote: That's also why these are billed once synched in Data Stream.

Your "provider" object Id will not be used as the Contact ID by an SF Entry Event based journey and you cannot configure the SF Entry without injecting. a Lead / user / Contact in some way, for the same reason.

I see these options:

a) change your entire contact model to use Lead or Contact ID (sure, you can use both - I guess your provider object was a way to avoid that, for good reason).

b) avoid the use of SF Entry events and use API events instead - these do and would also work without MC Connect, so they do not "impose" similar rules. You would need a form of APEX trigger setup in Sales Cloud to send API calls.

c) Accept the contacts created and clean up afterwards using contact deletion, but do your due diligence and take very great care with the performance data generated through your sendouts - tracking data, permissions, etc. which is all lost and would need a "migration", while the email is out in someone's inbox - this gets ugly.

If I had to choose - in a new system:

a)

Otherwise that ship has pretty much sailed - b).

It would not be the first MC Connect Out of the box feature that you can replace with a "better" solution, given you can spend the effort.